# Remove a list of provided letters from the start of the string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

I have a dataframe-df with column "Names" as below :

```
Names
AL GHAITHA & AL MOOSA
AL ASEEL ELECTRONICS T
SUNRISE SUPERMARKET-QU
EMARAT-AL SAFIYAH(6735
LULU CENTRE LLC EFT TE
THE MAX
```

Code :

```
remove_letters = ['AL ', 'THE ']

# my function below :

def remove_start_words(df, col, letters):
    for l in letters:
        for i in df.index:
            x = df.at[i, col]
            if x.startswith(l):
                df.at[i, col] = x[len(l):]
            else:
                df.at[i, col] = x

def remove_strings(self, df, col):
    for i in df.index:
        x = df.at[i, col]
        x = x.split(' ')
        if len(x) > 1:
            if len(x[1]) > 2:
                x[1] = ''.join(e for e in x[1] if e.isalnum())
                x = ' '.join(x[0:2])
                df.at[i, col] = x
            else:
                df.at[i, col] = x[0]
        else:
            df.at[i, col] = df.at[i, col]


def remove_end_digits(self, df, col):
    for i in df.index:
        x = df.at[i, col]
        df.at[i, col] = x.rstrip(string.digits)

# calling my function
remove_start_words(df=df, col='Names',
                          letters=remove_letters)

remove_strings(df=df, col='Names')
remove_end_digits(df=df, col='Names')
```

Now the problem is i have a dataframe of more than 1 million column values.
My code is not well optimized ? How to get a optimized solution ?

Issue 1 :
I can understand i have used 2 loops ( 1 for remove_letters and other for all the column values) that is causing slowness.

Is there a better way ? where i can check if the column values start with the letters mentioned in remove_letters list and strip them at one shot ?

Issue 2 & 3 : 
What is objective of the function - "remove_strings" :
Get only the 2 strings from the column names. For eg : ASEEL ELECTRONICS T
output will be : ASEEL ELECTRONICS

Is there a faster way for the functions : remove_strings,remove_end_digits

Main issue : Can all this 3 functions can be done at one shot all together ?

Expected dataframe:

```
Names
GHAITHA
ASEEL ELECTRONICS
SUNRISE SUPERMARKET
EMARAT-AL SAFIYAH
LULU CENTRE
MAX
```

NOTE : The function "remove_start_words" should check if any of the mentioned letters are starting in the "Names" if so, remove them.
For eg : "AL THEMAX" should be "THEMAX" not as "MAX" (removing both AL and THE)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about using `str.lstrip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you only wanted the words removed from the beginning of the sentence, you could use regular expression :

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = 'file3.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

words_to_remove = ["THE", "AL"]
regular_expression = '^' + '|'.join(words_to_remove)

df.Names = df.Names.apply(lambda x : re.sub(regular_expression, "", x))
```

the regular_expression expression variable would contain ^THE|AL in this case meaning THE or AL at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Thanks generally its said using "lamda" function is not optimized way of doing things. But i like your answer. Is there any other way to use it avoiding lamda ? Also my question is how can i use all my functions in one go ? All the answers were responding to just one function of mine

Comment: @pyds_learner I don't know where you heard it is not a good idea to use lambdas but they are totally fine if you are using them where necessary, and this one is completely fine. Also, it maybe a good idea to upvote the answers you like.

Comment: It's slower to use apply+ lambda than to use other str functions but in your case no predefined function does the job completely , one go with a lambda is a lot faster than going through your list 2-3 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace method like this:

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = 'file3.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

words_to_remove = ["THE", "AL"]

for word in words_to_remove:
    df.Names = df.Names.str.replace(word, "")

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, Friends, i am looking for one shot solution for the issues. Also with the above solution if the column values is "AL THEMAX" is should be "THEMAX". but the output is "MAX" it removes both AL and THE as its in a loop

Answer (score 0):

A couple minutes of searching on Google tells me that

```
def stripper(delete_list):
    def delete(item):
        nonlocal delete_list
        for rm in delete_list:
            item = item.lstrip(rm)
        return item
    return delete

df['Names'] = df['Names'].apply(stripper(['AL', 'THE'])
```

should do the trick.